# Tkinter Scrollbar question (independent scrollable length indexed to custom range)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm having trouble wording this properly.  What I'm looking to do is create a scrollbar that is indexed to a range I set that will return its position when it's moved/updated.  In the simplest form, let's just say I print the position of the bar each time it's updated.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  I assume it involves setting a custom range and some sort of sensitivity.

The ultimate plan is to use the scrollbar to scroll through a matplotlib chart with a time series as the x-axis, but I believe that will be easy enough once I get the scrollbar setup.

Thanks!

```
self.scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal",
                            command=lambda e1, e2, e3=None:
                                self.scroll_update(e1, e2))

def scroll_update(self, action, val):
    if action == "moveto":
        print(val)
    elif action == "scroll":
        pass
```

Comment: There has to be a two-way connection between the scrollbar and the scrolled widget - the reverse direction is typically something like the `yscrollcommand=` option of a `Text` or 'Canvas'.  The scrollbar tells the widget that the user performed an action, the widget updates its internal state based on that action, the widget tells the scrollbar its new position - without this closed loop, the scrollbar would never actually move.  You need to do the scrollbar update yourself if you aren't using a standard widget.  (But note that a `Scale` might actually be the better solution in your case.)

Comment: Scale is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jasonharper pointed out, it's much easier to use a `Scale` in your case:

```
from tkinter import *

on_update = lambda e: print(e)

#                          |in pixels| |resolution| |the slider, pixels| |switch value display
s=Scale(command=on_update, length=250, to=1000,     sliderlength=50,     showvalue=False)
s.pack()

print(s.get())
s.set(20) #  note, this also executes the "command" property
```

Hope that's helpful!